# Is there a semantic wiki engine that runs on the microsoft stack (.NET, SQL Server)?

Tags: .net, sql-server, wiki-engine

I am looking for a semantic wiki engine that runs on .net and sql server. Anyone know of any? If so, is it any good?

If not, next best alternative?

**Edit**
Sematic media wiki can be [hooked up to SQL Server](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aExternal_Data) (in theory).

> A note about database systems support:
>   MySQL and Postgres (i.e. PostgreSQL)
>   should work fully. Oracle support
>   works only on MediaWiki 1.16 or
>   greater. To connect to MSSQL (i.e.
>   SQLServer), you may need to either
>   install Microsoft drivers for PHP for
>   SQL Server (which works only in
>   Windows), or use the MSSQLBackCompat
>   extension. If you use the extension,
>   you will need to specify "mssqlold"
>   (not "mssql") as the database type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at SCrewTurn Wiki (http://www.screwturn.eu/)?  I believe this can even be downloaded and configured through the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Comment: Awesome. I will take a look. . .